# How do I detect a new Intent if my app already has focus?

Tags: android, android-intent, focus

I have an application that connects to a server and can hold the connection for a long time.

I have another application that automates stuff. E.g. it can launch the above client based on rules and pass parameters to make it do stuff without user action (inside an Intent).

Now: This works fine if the client application isn't running or doesn't have focus. I catch onResume() and extract the parameters from the intent.

However if the client already is in the foreground (because the user didn't close it after last use) and it is called from the automate-app (e.g. based on time) it keeps focus all the time and doesn't lose it. So how do I detect it being launched again? onResume() doesn't seem to fire, nor does onNewIntent().

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) states the following instructions:

> This is called for activities that set **launchMode to "singleTop"** in their package, or if a **client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent)**. In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> **Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent**.

If you follow everything, your method onNewIntent() should be called.